# How we can use adjusted price in combination with price limit in a stock market?

Tags: adjusted, financial-markets

How we can use adjusted price in combination with price limit in stock market? suppose that we have a price limit in a stock market. For example if yesterday last price is `X`, today price range for training is `X-a%` and `X+a%`. We don't have any problem when we are using non-adjusted prices but when we use adjusted prices (as a time series) and using below formula (for example for today open price):

```
today_open_price_change = (P(today_open_price)-P(yesterday_close_price)/P(yesterday_close_price)
```

In a time series we have values bigger  than `a%` (price limit percentage). How we should adjust this percentage (`a%`) for adjusted price time series?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question completely, but the standard practice is to use the logarithms of the stock price and look at the differences.